# Why does the Java compiler say that the variable might not have been initialized?

Tags: java, compiler-errors

```
static int fib(int n) {
    int beforePrevious;
    int previous;
    int curr;
    if (n <= 1) {
        return n;
    } else {
        beforePrevious = 0;
        previous = 1;
        for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
            curr = beforePrevious + previous;
            beforePrevious = previous;
            previous = curr;
        }
        return curr;
    }
}
```

Hi, in this code why does the compiler say "Variable curr might not have been initialized"? For n >=2, the else clause will run and curr will be assigned a value at least once.

On a related not, if I need to assign a value in such cases, is it a good practice to assign default values to other variables also?

Comment: What if the for loop never loops? The compiler cannot know in advance what value `n` has, and so the error makes sense. Why not simply give curr some default value?

Comment: Understood, thanks for your reply. So shall the other variables also be given a default value?